# How to limit input to numbers 0-9 only?

Tags: javascript, input, numbers

I need to write a code in a way only the numbers 1 - 9 are able to be input into a text field.

Whatever the number in that is input into the text field, will output of the timetables from 1-9 for that number.

For example, if the number "1" was input: 1 x 1 = 1  to  1 x 9 = 9 will be listed.

I can't figure out how to limit the input numbers to only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function table(){
  var integerInput = document.getElementById("integer");
  var integer = Number(integerInput.value);

  var displayField = document.getElementById("display");
  //Reset the innerHTML when a new integer is inserted
  displayField.innerHTML = "";
  //Loop from 1 -> 9
  for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      //Append the current times table to the HTML
      displayField.innerHTML += `${integer} x ${i} = ${integer*i}<br>`
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter an integer from 1 to 9:
  <input id="integer" type="text">
  <button onclick="table()" onclick="table2()">Generate times table</button>
  <p id="display"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using `<input type="number">`

Comment: I can still enter any number @User863

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that your `integer` variable is an integer between 1 and 9:

```js
function table() {
  var integerInput = document.getElementById("integer");
  var integer = Number(integerInput.value);
  if (!Number.isInteger(integer) || integer < 1 || integer > 9) {
    throw new Error('Number is not an integer between 1 and 9');
  }
  var displayField = document.getElementById("display");
  //Reset the innerHTML when a new integer is inserted
  displayField.innerHTML = "";
  //Loop from 1 -> 9
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    //Append the current times table to the HTML
    displayField.innerHTML += `${integer} x ${i} = ${integer*i}<br>`
  }
}
```

```html
Enter an integer from 1 to 9:
<input id="integer" type="text">
<button onclick="table()" onclick="table2()">Generate times table</button>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Another option is to use a form with a pattern of `[1-9]` (though unfortunately, you can't combine a `pattern` with an `input type="number"`):

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var integerInput = document.getElementById("integer");
  var integer = Number(integerInput.value);
  if (!Number.isInteger(integer) || integer < 1 || integer > 9) {
    throw new Error('Number is not an integer between 1 and 9');
  }
  var displayField = document.getElementById("display");
  //Reset the innerHTML when a new integer is inserted
  displayField.innerHTML = "";
  //Loop from 1 -> 9
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    //Append the current times table to the HTML
    displayField.innerHTML += `${integer} x ${i} = ${integer*i}<br>`
  }
});
```

```html
Enter an integer from 1 to 9:
<form>
  <input id="integer" pattern="[1-9]">
  <button>Generate times table</button>
  <p id="display"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function table(){
  var integerInput = document.getElementById("integer");
  var integer = Number(integerInput.value);

  var displayField = document.getElementById("display");
  //Reset the innerHTML when a new integer is inserted
  displayField.innerHTML = "";
  //Loop from 1 -> 9
  for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      //Append the current times table to the HTML
      displayField.innerHTML += `${integer} x ${i} = ${integer*i}<br>`
  }
}

function numbersOnly(input){
    var regex = /[^1-9]/;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter an integer from 1 to 9:
  <input id="integer" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" maxlength="1">
  <button onclick="table()" onclick="table2()">Generate times table</button>
  <p id="display"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

The main changes I made are:

```
function numbersOnly(input){
    var regex = /[^1-9]/;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

and

```
<input id="integer" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" maxlength="1">
```

**Edit**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function table(){
  var integerInput = document.getElementById("integer");
  var integer = Number(integerInput.value);

  display_iterator(integer, "display")
  display_iterator(integer, "display2")
}

function display_iterator(integer, display_id){
    var displayField = document.getElementById(display_id);
    //Reset the innerHTML when a new integer is inserted
    displayField.innerHTML = "";
    //Loop from 1 -> 9
    for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        //Append the current times table to the HTML
        displayField.innerHTML += `${integer} x ${i} = ${integer*i}<br>`
    }
}

function numbersOnly(input){
    var regex = /[^1-9]/;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter an integer from 1 to 9:
  <input id="integer" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" maxlength="1">
  <button onclick="table()">Generate times table</button>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p id="display"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p id="display2"></p>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! If I wanted to display a duplicate times table list next to the original list, what would I do?

Comment: I just used a <table> to arrange the 2 displays. For the second display, I used another <p> tag with a different id to duplicate the first display.